# using typename from template parameter in class

Tags: c++

```
//A.h
template <class T>
class A
{
public:
    typename T::Type x; //(1) compile time error: C2039 'Type': is not a member of 'B'
    void f();
};
template <class T>
void A<T>::f() 
{ 
  typename T::Type x1; //(2) but no errors here
}

//B.h 
#include "A.h"

class B : public A<B>
{
public:
    using Type = int;
};

//main.cpp
#include "B.h"

int main()
{
    B x;
}
```

Why there is error in (1) but no errors in (2)?
How can I store a variable of type `typename T::Type` and write function like `func(typename T::Type)` in A class?

I don't know why this class design was done and I don't want to change class hierarchy or template parameters in code because there are a lot of classes inherited from A and code is quite confusing. So please no advices in this way.

P.S. Sorry for not clear question name, but I cannot invent better one.

Comment: For the definition of A, B::Type has to be known.
For the definition of B, A<B> has to be known.

This is not solvable. The definition of both types depend on each other and thus cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 3):

While you are define `class B : public A<B>` the class `B` is not defined but you try to use this class in A. At this point of time, the compiler has no knowledge if there will be a definition of `using Type = int;`.

gcc provides a more readable error message: "invalid use of incomplete type 'class B'"

`void A<T>::f()` will never be instantiated, so you will not see an error message.

The bad news: You have no chance to do any kind of forward declaration in this situation as you have a full circular dependency.

Answer (score 1):

```
class B : public A<B>
```

`B` is incomplete at this point. It is not known yet that it has a `Type` member. So instantiation of `A::x` fails.

By contrast, `A<T>::f()` is never instantiated. If you do instantiate it, it is likely to happen when `B` is a complete type, so `B::Type` should already be known.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that due to circularity in definitions - `A<B>` can't be defined until `B` is defined, and `B` can't be defined until `A<B>` is defined.

What you can do is add a level of indirection, going through a "traits" class that's independent of the ultimate definition of `B`.

Example:

```
template <typename T>
struct traits{};

template <class T>
class A
{
public:
    typename traits<T>::Type x; 
};

class B;

template <>
struct traits<B>
{
    using Type = int;
};

class B : public A<B>
{
public:
    using Type = typename traits<B>::Type;
};


int main()
{
    B x;
}
```